# BCP Copy Error for Large Text File

Tags: sql, bcp

I am attempting to import a large text file (40GB) into an sql database using the bcp utility but I keep getting this error:

```
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 9162000
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 1105
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Could not allocate space for object 'dbo.CLAIMS_CAS_ALL_2004_UPDATED_20101002_HUMANA' in database 'Claims' because the 'PRIMARY' filegroup is full. Create disk space by deleting unneeded files, dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the filegroup.

BCP copy in failed
```

This is after doing a batch size of a 1000 accounts. I set autogrowth to 50% but I still had that error. What could I do next?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the disk is running out of space where the SQL server is installed. 
Possible fix is to increase the disk space.

Comment: I got 292GB left on my hard drive. Maybe changing the size allocation on the database might help.